# Return COUNT in a request

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have this request :

```
  SELECT id_user
    FROM posts
GROUP BY id_user
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

...which will return the `id_user`, ordered by their number of occurrence in the `posts` table.

But along with the `id_user` information, I would like to keep track of the COUNT(*) and store it somewhere, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT id_user, 
         COUNT(*) AS numPosts
    FROM posts
GROUP BY id_user
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

The column alias in the example, `numPosts`, can then be referenced in whatever you're already using to get the `id_user` column values.

Comment: obviously it works too for it is the same answer ! thanks again

Answer (score 3):

you can do:

```
  select id_user, count(*) total_count
    FROM posts
GROUP BY id_user
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

That way you can still retrieve the user id and the total times it appeared in the table