# MySQL query already GROUPed and ORDERed : how to ORDER inside the GROUPs?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this query:

```
SELECT id_user, COUNT(*) as count
FROM posts
GROUP BY id_user
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

which gives me the id_user ordered by occurrences, and the number of each occurrence.
Can I get, in the same request, the LAST post from each 'id_user'? i.e. I want to select the last 'post' too, but when I do

```
SELECT id_user, post, COUNT(*) as count
```

Tthe value in 'post' isn't the last one (nor the first one; actually I don't know how groups are ordered). Should I run another query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return COUNT in a request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721314/return-count-in-a-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to do it in one query:

```
SELECT 
  p.id_user,
  ap.post AS last_post,
  COUNT(*) as count
FROM 
  posts p
  JOIN posts ap on (
    p.id_user = ap.id_user
    AND ap.post_id = (
      SELECT MAX(post_id) FROM posts ip WHERE p.id_user = ip.id_user
    )
GROUP BY 
  p.id_user,
  ap.post
ORDER BY 
  COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe u can accomplish this by adding `max(post_id) last_post` to your `select`.

Comment: hm that's close but it returns the value of post_id, not the the value of 'post' attached to this post_id

Comment: it's still useful cause now i just have to run a query WHERE post_id=last_post